# PHP background process to do something a day?

Tags: php, linux, process, background

I'm trying to run my PHP script on linux server once a day automatically without having to press something, only once and process keeps running till a specific date,

How do I do this WITHOUT making a high traffic load on the server?

what i did so far is using [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) function to keep it running and also using [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function in a while loop to check every specific time how much left for the next day but it seemed a high process for the server

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a Linux server, there's a much easier way.  Simply create a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) ([tutorial](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)) to run the script once a day.

I've never used it, but a Windows server should have something called "Task Scheduler" to do the same thing.

Comment: yah sorry forgot to mention its a linux debian server, thanks for your note but could you clarify this cron job ? i read some details but i didnt get it, thanks

Comment: @Osa I added a link to a tutorial/help page

Answer (score 1):

```
00 11 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/you/your_script.php
```

This is a cron job that will run your script at 11:00 AM everyday.

Comment: It stops when it's done -- Either execution is done or something calls exit() from inside the script.

Comment: @joar he says everyday which means forever, how to manage running crons ?

Comment: the cronjob isn't running. Cron is always running; intepreting the timimg conditions and if they match the current time, Cron will execute the linux command via bash/sh.

Comment: @Osa, you can run multiple cron jobs at once and you can remove them if you want. For more information on adding the job(s), use [crontab](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)

Comment: @WouterH, look at my code; the first part of it calls php, the second part then calls the script.